# Validate a form with using Jquery - Problems

Tags: html, jquery

Sorry for my bad English.

Okay, let's go: when I try to validate my form using jQuery, it works just the else option.

I'm considering a spacing in between names, for identify the name input, for as fullname. But in doing so, nothing appears in my console.

Someone help me please.

```
$('form#form1').submit(function() {
    var fname = $('input[name=fullname]').val()
    var pho = $('input[name=phone]').val()
    var mai = $('input[name=email]').val()
    var amount = fname.split(' ').lenght
    var splitStr = fname.split(' ')

    if(amount >= 2) {
        console.log('It worked!')

        for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
            console.log(splitStr[1])
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Wrong!")
        return false;
    }

    return  false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It supposes to be `fname.split(' ').length`.
Writing `fname.split(' ').lenght` will result in amount == undefined and thus (undefined >= 2) will always be false.